# Spring Boot Entity DynamicUpdate

Tags: java, spring, api, spring-boot

I am writing API on Spring Boot have an issue with partial update of entity. When I want to update for example just name of user, spring sees other fields as null and replaces data with nulls in Database. As i read in documentation @DynamicUpdate must fix this issue but it is not working for me.

Here is my user Entity.

```
@Entity
@Table(name="users")
@DynamicUpdate
public class User {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;
    //other fields...

}
```

Comment: Did you tried `Entity(dynamicUpdate = true)'

Answer (score 1):

> Use merge instead

```
Entity en = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().get(id);
en.setName("abc");
sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().merge(en);
```

> **Performance issue with Entity(
>           dynamicUpdate = true
>   )**
>   In a large table with many columns (legacy design) or contains large data volumes, update some unmodified columns are absolutely unnecessary and great impact on the system performance.